# Exibir apenas uma view a partir de um link

Tags: vraptor

sou iniciante no vRaptor bla bla

To querendo ao clicar num botão da view e redirecionar para uma página apenas de visualização. Preciso criar um controller só para isso ou um

```
<li><a href="../sistema/pagina.jsp">CLIQUE AQUI</a></li>
```

resolve? 
Qual a melhor forma?

Comment: Verifiquei aqui e preciso criar um controller para isso. Entretanto, estou procurando solução para o seguinte erro: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are two rules that matches the uri '/teste' with method GET:

Comment: Resolvi aqui,pessoal. Dei clean, parecia problema de compilação no projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema foi resolvido, mas uma possível solução para o erro:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are two rules that matches the
>   uri '/teste' with method GET:

Na verdade é porque você tem dois mapeamentos de URL iguais com um mesmo nome. 
Uma solução seria entrar com o caminho completo, controller/metodo ou se não utilizar a anotação

> @Path("seu endereço")

Mesmo assim fique atento para a duplicidade de endereços, eu particularmente prefiro utilizar o padrão controller/metodo.